# Help finding boundary, accumulation, closure set, and boundary of the closure set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I'm given the set $S=\{r\in \mathbb{Q}:r \ge \sqrt{2}\}$ and asked to find

a. $\operatorname{bd}S = [\sqrt{2},\infty)$

b. $S'= [\sqrt{2},\infty)$

c.  $\operatorname{cl} S = [\sqrt{2},\infty)$

d. $\operatorname{bd}(\operatorname{cl} S) = \{\sqrt{2}\}$

My understandings of a boundary point of $S$ is every neighborhood of $x$ must have a point in $S$ and also a point not in $S$. By this logic it's easy to see every number n greater or equal to $\sqrt{2}$ is a boundary point for $S$.

For accumulation point it follows the same logic as boundary except every deleted neighborhood of $x$ should have a point in $S$ other than itself.

For the closure of the set I know $\operatorname{cl} S = S \cup S'= S \cup \operatorname{bd} S$
So it seems clear $\operatorname{cl}S=\operatorname{bd} S=S'$

Lastly for $\operatorname{bd}([\sqrt{2}, \infty))$ I can easily see that $\operatorname{bd}(\operatorname{cl} S)=\{\sqrt{2}\}$.

Am I correct?

Comment: I noticed that you have something like $[\sqrt 2, \infty)$, which implies some kind of environment; I guess it R.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$, the usual topology, you'd be right, yes.

Comment: Learn Mathjax to format your posts!

Comment: You should have stated that $S$ is to be considered as a subset of the  space  $\Bbb R.$.... BTW a common notation for the boundary of $S$ is $\partial S$ or $\partial (S)$ or Fr($S$)....Fr is for Frontier ..The code for $\partial$ is  \partial... Your conclusions are correct

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are correct.

So that this moves off the Unanswered-Q list.